# Does it make sense to discuss entropy change at different time frames?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, time, cooling

The classic cup of tea cooling problem, why does it not violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics. The classic answer would be that the increase in the entropy of the surrounding is greater than the decrease in entropy of the cooling cup of tea. (Treating the surrounding as a reservoir at T).

However, I have also seen discussions that suggest the entropy increase from heating the cup of tea is greater than the entropy decrease from cooling, but this heating occurs before cooling (i.e. different time frame). Would it make sense to discuss the 2nd law for two processes that occurred at different time?

Comment: You need to involve the full system in questions regarding entropy, which you do by taking all the times that processes involved in the system take place

Comment: Sure it would make sense if you do it correctly (by also taking into account the change in entropy including the surroundings, during heating).